# Entity Framework - CommitFailureHandler.ClearTransactionHistory()

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, wcf, entity-framework-6

I have an issue that I'm running into regarding the `commitFailureHandler.ClearTransactionHistory();` method in Entity Framework 6.1. When I run this for the very first time, I get an exception that states `'dbo.EFTransactionHistory'` is invalid.

```
InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
 HResult=-2146232060
 Message=Invalid object name 'dbo.EFTransactionHistory'.
 Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
 ErrorCode=-2146232060
 Class=16
 LineNumber=1
 Number=208
 Procedure=""
 Server=********
 State=1
```

I checked in the database & of course that table does not exist. Of course we should be executing this method every time the application starts up. In this case, it is a WCF service & I made a custom Service Initializer so whenever the mex is initiated or the very first service call comes in it initializes some resources that the service will need.

Here is what I have in my web.config for my service:

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="WSI.Common.DataAccess.Configuration.EntityFramework.TransactionDbConfiguration, WSI.Common.DataAccess">
```

Here I extend the DbConfiguration class with the following code:

```
public class TransactionDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
     {
     public TransactionDbConfiguration()
         {
         SetTransactionHandler(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, () => new CommitFailureHandler(c => new DbTransactionContext(c)));
         SetExecutionStrategy(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
         }
     }
```

Next is my code that I extend the TransactionContext class with:

```
    public class DbTransactionContext : TransactionContext
        {
        public DbTransactionContext(DbConnection dbConnection) : base(dbConnection)
            {

            }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
       modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionRow>().ToTable("EFTransactionHistory");
       }
   }
```

Then in my ServiceInitializer class, I call a static method by passing an instance of the DbContext like so:

```
protected static void Initialize(DbContext dbContext)
    {
    if (dbContext != null)
        {
        using (CommitFailureHandler commitFailureHandler = CommitFailureHandler.FromContext(dbContext))
            {
            if (commitFailureHandler != null)
                {
                commitFailureHandler.ClearTransactionHistory();
                //commitFailureHandler.PruneTransactionHistory();
                }
            }
         }
     }
```

Of course if I remove the `commitFailureHandler.ClearTransactionHistory();` & I run the application, once I update any of my entities in the database during the normal course of when the service runs, it will create the `dbo.EFTransactionHistory` table. Then I stop the service, I include the `commitFailureHandler.ClearTransactionHistory();` method it will works.

Some how the `ClearTransactionHistory()` should be checking to see if the table exists before attempting to delete the rows from the table or it triggers the `OnModelCreating()` method.

I've been working on this for a few days now & I would love to find a way to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following in your `Initialize` method:

```
dbContext.Database.Initialize(true);
```

This should trigger/force the DB initialization.

Comment: I added the 'dbContext.Database.Initialize(true);' just after I check to see if the dbContext is null or not in my static Initialize() method. I still get the same problem. Now I should note that I'm not doing the code first approach...I took a model first approach to create my database & then created my entities from that. I don't know if this makes a difference. I would think not.